# Чтение бинарного файла на си

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

В файле записана структура в бинарном виде, сначала идет массив char(слово), потом число и все это повторяется с новой строки, количество которых известно заранее. Вопрос простой и одновременно сложный, а как собственно считать эти значения (пишу их в структуру), пока не выходит как я написал.

```
 // структура
    
    struct st
    {
        char* nam;
        int count;
    };
    // сама запись в файл
     FILE* fp = fopen("file.bin", "wb+");
        char new_str = '\n';
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Can't open file\n");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            fwrite(&(st[i].nam), sizeof(char), strlen(st[i].nam), fp);
            fwrite(&(st[i].count), sizeof(int), 1, fp);
            fwrite(&(new_str), sizeof(char), 1, fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    
        FILE* fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
            if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("Can't open file\n");
                return;
            }
            rewind(fp);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                fread(&(st[i].nam), sizeof(char), strlen(st[i].nam), fp);
                fread(&(st[i].count), sizeof(int), 1, fp);
            }
            fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Приведите пример структуры файла

Comment: В бинарных файлах нету "новой строки". Есть только бинарные данные (байты).

Comment: Строку я добавил самостоятельно, перенос

Comment: Что вы хотели сказать написав `strlen(st[i].nam)` ? массив символов nam уже чем-то инициализирован?

Comment: Пример структуры, в бинарнике: АмeЯ   
 нe A  
@нe°

Comment: Если длина строки не постоянная, то читайте по кускам и выполняйте разбор данных. Пример не показателен.

Comment: Приведите код - структуры и того, как вы записываете в файл. Без этого вряд ли получится... Особенно если вы читаете столько, сколько **уже** содержится :) - `strlen(st[i].nam)` при чтении как-то странновато. "Странно, если не сказать большего" (с)

Comment: подправил вопрос выше

Comment: Если перед телом строки записать её длину - будет намного проще. Кроме того, я не уверен, что операция `fwrite(&(st[i].nam)` пишет именно тело строки, а не значение указателя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо при записи сначала писать число выводимых байтов строки. При чтении - читать число байтов, выделять необходимую память и уже в нее записывать.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int len = strlen(st[i].nam);
        fwrite(&len,sizeof(len),1,fp);
        fwrite(st[i].nam, sizeof(char), len, fp);
        fwrite(&(st[i].count), sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    }
```

Чтение:

```
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int len;
            fread(&len,sizeof(len),1,fp);
            st[i].nam = (char*)calloc(len+1);
            fread(st[i].nam, sizeof(char), len, fp);
            fread(&(st[i].count), sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        }
```

В пределах одной программы, когда все указатели на месте и указывают на строки с выделенной памятью - может проскочить неверное чтение. Чтобы действительно убедиться что все верно, писать надо в одной программе, а читать в другой.

Comment: А как я при чтение узнаю size? Его нужно же вычислить, только вопрос как, данные то у нас в строчку идут, даже строки не подсчитаешь

Comment: Так вы же его при записи первым записываете! Записали размер, потом строку. Считали размер, подготовили строку, считали строку. Я же ясно в коде написал.

Comment: Это да, но где у вас for...i<size, вот этот size откуда мне брать

Comment: А! Так а откуда вы его снйчас берете? :) Перед тем как писать элементы массива - бобавьте еще запись, сколько их всего. А потом считывайте первым же значение.